# How to configure automatic builds on Azure to use c#6 compiler

Tags: c#-6.0

I'm ready to publish a MVC5 application using C#6 compiler to azure.

My automatic builds return errors about not understanding nameof, etc.

Is there anyway to change some configuration so my builds and application uses C#6 compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally installed the nuget package called `Microsoft.Net.Installer (1.0.0-beta2)`.

This worked like a charm and I don't know if there's another way to do it, but since I only have 1 project this wasn't a problem.